# intermittent background-load bug in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

Heres the story:

When I load the following page in chrome (verified across 2 computers), it seems like about 1 in 5 refreshes results in display errors.

Often, the background image only loads halfway down the the screen, and the bottom half displays only white (which is weird b/c I have the background set to black under the image.)

There is at least one other incorrect way that it displays which is a less exaggerated version of the other problem.

Since it only happens sometimes and only on chrome (as far as I can tell) and only on one page of the site, I have ignored this issue for more pressing concerns; but I develop in chrome so I am constantly reminded of it.

I have absolutely no clue why this kind of thing would happen and even less of a clue how to remedy it.  Any insight anyone might have would be greatly appreciated.

[The page](http://www.roughgiraffed.com/portfolio.php)

Comment: As far as I can tell, that page is loading okay in Chrome for me (background image goes about 1/2 way down and the rest is black and it blends nicely into the background image). I do sometimes experience a strange background issue in Chrome but it always seems to involve a site with a self signed SSL certificate.

Comment: Thank you for checking.  I'm just plain stumped about all of this.  But oh well. I have bigger fish to fry so to speak.  I will definitely post If I find any resolution to my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to load your page in Safari. If you see same problem, means you missed a bracket or semi column in your css. Webkit browsers seem to handle css errors this way. I had same problem happening to me once. My css file was over 2800 lines. It took some time to find the error. Best.

Comment: Hmmmm.... I just tried in Safari, I was unable to repeat the error.  I did however get the page to not display at all sometimes by ferociously clicking refresh, but I am not sure if its related.  
In any case, Ill triple check my css...

Answer (score 0):

See the following link:

[Issue with background color and Google Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/425216/problem-with-background-color-and-google-chrome)

This fixed the problem for me...