# Website look different in same version of Chrome on different computers(Mac/Windows)

Tags: windows, html, macos, css, google-chrome

I just cant figure why on **same version Chrome**:
Mac- most of the website divs well organised but some of them just disordered.
Windows- Working perfectly as it should.
Same versions Chrome- work fine in both computers on other browser.
I tried refresh cash but it wont help.
any suggestions?

This is how its looks in Mac Version :

[image: mac version] –

This is how its looks in Windows version :

[image: windows version]

Any ideas?

Comment: You'll need to be more specific. What doesn't look the same?

Comment: @DLeh this is how it's look in Mac Version : http://imagizer.imageshack.com/img673/5983/Gccz8P.png

Comment: @DLeh This is how it's look in Windows version : http://imagizer.imageshack.com/img673/9490/sTiPKD.png                         Anyideas?

Comment: upload the images into the question, as they pertain to the question. I'm not saying i can help you, i'm saying nobody can help with the information you've provided so far.

Comment: @DLeh hope it help's me .

Comment: you'll need to provide some code and some examples of what you've tried if you expect help.

Comment: @DLeh i dont know even what to try,because it's dosent make sense. It's save browser save version- i really dont know what to do, or what can i try :(

Comment: Check for unexpected user style sheet in Mac. I had once problem with CSS class .clear, which was only in some Macbooks already defined.

Comment: Inspect via the console and see what rules are causing the peculiar behaviour, this shouldn't happen unless you have another conflicting stylesheet

Comment: This might be relevant: [Problem with background color and Google Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/425216/problem-with-background-color-and-google-chrome)

Comment: @showdev tried it.. dosent helo very much it's really hard to work like that, any more ideas?

Comment: Sorry, I'd have to see your code to investigate further.

Comment: @showdev you can skype that i can send the code? it's critical :'\